# Echo commands and output to file from interactive shell

Tags: bash, io-redirection, interactive

I am looking for a graceful way to have bash write both the command I executed, followed by the output of that command to a file from an interactive prompt.  Such that running a command like this:

```
$ls -alh > list_dir
```

would write something resembling this to list_dir:

```
$ls -alh > list_dir
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 21 13:30 .
drwx------ 5 root root 4.0K Dec 21 13:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  842 Dec 21 13:09 file
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Dec 21 13:29 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Dec 21 13:29 file2
```

I have found many articles with solutions that claim to work within a script, but nothing that has worked from an interactive shell.  For example, many people suggest adding this toward the top of a script:

```
set -x
```

If I enter this in my shell, the commands are printed (although not nicely) to standard output, but I have not managed to figure out how to include them in output redirection.

I also saw many people suggest using script to do this.  This is the closest I've come to finding what I'm looking for, but I don't always want EVERYTHING to be recorded.  I want to be in control of which commands are redirected to a file.

Does anyone know of a good solution to this?  I'm open to more out-of-the-box ideas so long as they're not too clunky for regular use.

Comment: Do you require the redirection to be part of the command listed in the file? For instance, in your example, would having `ls -ahl` instead of `ls -ahl > list_dir` as the first line of the file be acceptable?

Comment: Would you take an `expect` script which does the same as `script` except it allows you to type something like `~l` to turn logging on and off?

Answer (score 3):

set -x option puts your script in debugging mode. Where actual command is echoed to stderr. So you need to redirect both stdout and stderr to somefile. try this 
`your_script.sh &> outputfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The `xtrace` output is going to stderr *before* the command is evaluated including before the redirections are performed.

So in:

```
set -x # or set -o xtrace
echo test 2> file
```

The `+ echo test` goes to wherever stderr was going to, then the shell opens `file` on fd 2 and then runs `echo test`. If you want the `+ echo test` to go to `file`, you'd need:

```
{ echo test; } 2> file
```

This time, the redirection is performed for the command group and then the `echo test` command is evaluated (and the `+ echo test` written to stderr which at that point goes to `file`).

Note that some shells like AT&T `ksh` will also output a `+ 2> file`. It's also bogus in some versions of `mksh`.

That also means that the stderr of any command run within that command group will go the `file`. To work around that, you'd need:

```
set -x
{
  cmd 2>&3 3>&-
} 3>&2 2> file
```

That is keep a copy of the original stderr (on fd 3) and restore it for the commands inside the command group.

With `bash`, an alternative is to use the `$BASH_XTRACEFD` special variable:

```
exec 7> file
BASH_XTRACEFD=7

set -x
echo test
```

If you want a *nice* `xtrace` output, try `zsh`. Also note that it can be customized with the `$PS4` special variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be to add a function to your `.bashrc` file such as this:

`my_run(){
   echo $@
   eval $@
}`

Be sure to `source .bashrc` after adding the function. Then, using your example, from the command line type:

`my_run ls -ahl >list_dir`.

If you also want to see the output on the screen use this instead:

`my_run ls -ahl | tee list_dir`

If you don't want to use a function, here are a few ways to do this from the command line:

`echo "ls -ahl" >list_dir; eval $@ >>list_dir`

If you also want to see the output on the screen, either one of these will work.

`echo "ls -ahl" >list_dir; eval $@ | tee -a list_dir`

`echo "ls -ahl" | tee list_dir | bash >>list_dir`